Error uploading APK to Google Play: "You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle" despite android:debuggable="false" in Xamarin Forms
I'm trying to publish my Xamarin Forms app on Google Play, but I keep receiving the error: "You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play." I have already set android:debuggable="false" in my AndroidManifest.xml as shown below:
<application
    android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:label="وديني كابتن"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/info">
</application>

I was expecting this setting to ensure that my APK is not debuggable and thus suitable for publishing on Google Play. However, I still encounter the error. Here’s what I have tried so far:

Clean and rebuild the project.
Manually checked other parts of the project to ensure no other settings override this attribute.
Reviewed the build configuration to ensure it's set to 'Release' and not 'Debug'.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully publish my app?

You can refer to the comment of s3c: How do I generate Google Play Console upload key using Xamarin Forms, try his solution.
